# Client is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to host a discord bot on my ubuntu server.

Everything was working but for some reason it just stopped working and it shows the same error all the time, no matter what i change.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({intents: ["MessageContent"]});

client.login("My bots token")

console.log(client);
client.on('message', message => {

        if (message.content === '!hello') {

                message.channel.send('Nazdar!');

        }
})

client.once('ready', () => {

        console.log('Ready!');

        })
```

The error message:

```
> 0|index    |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
> 0|index    |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
> 0|index    |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
> 0|index    |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
> 0|index    | ReferenceError: Client is not defined
> 0|index    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/root/pives-bot/index.js:5:1)
> 0|index    |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
> 0|index    |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
> 0|index    |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
> 0|index    |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
> 0|index    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v19.6.1/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:33:23)
> 0|index    |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1275:14)
> 0|index    |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1329:10)
> 0|index    |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1133:32)
> 0|index    |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:12)
>
```

I tried changing all forms of uppercase or lowercase characters, but still the same issue. Thanks for every help!!

Comment: Was there anything before in the error message? What you posted is only a tracestack and is not  currently helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest versions of discord.js like v14 then you want to change a few things like requiring the discord.js and creating the client.

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');
```

```
const client = new Client({
    intents: [ GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent ],
    partials: [ Partials.Message, Partials.MessageContent ]
});
```

This may or not be the cause of your issue because of having completely different versions installed.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions or need further assistance.

Comment: I‘m curious why you define partials here as they‘re more „only do this if you know exactly what you‘re doing“, could you explain why you‘d use them in this case?

Comment: @lupus Partials are a feature of the Discord.js library that allows for caching of certain types of message data in a partial form. When using the partials option, you can specify which types of data to cache.

For example, setting Partials.Message enables caching of partial message objects, which contain information such as the message ID, author, timestamp, and channel ID. Setting Partials.MessageContent enables caching of the message content for partial messages, which can be useful for processing or filtering messages based on their content.